# Javascript - Connect Four game validation

Tags: javascript

I have the following test multidimensional array that mirrors a standard Connect Four gameboard:

```
var board = [['-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
             ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
             ['-','-','-','R','R','R','R'],
             ['-','-','-','Y','Y','R','Y'],
             ['-','-','-','Y','R','Y','Y'],
             ['-','-','Y','Y','R','R','R']];
```

I'm writing a js validation that checks each element in the board array for a 4-of-a-kind match either across, down, or diagonally.  Looking at the test board above, my validator should return `R` as the correct answer as there is a connecting match of 4 `R` elements in the third row.  Here's my code:

```
function fourTogether(a,b,c,d) {
   return (a != '-') && (a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d);
}

function connectFour(board) {
  // check RIGHT
   for (row=col=0; row<3 && col<7; row++, col++) {
       if (fourTogether(board[row][col], board[row+1][col], board[row+2][col], board[row+3][col])) {
         return board[row][col];
       }
     } 
    //  check DOWN    
   for (row=col= 0; row<6 && col<4; row++, col++) {
       if (fourTogether(board[row][col], board[row][col+1], board[row][col+2], board[row][col+3])) {
         return board[row][col];
       }
     }    
    //  check DIAGONAL to RIGHT
   for (row=col=0; row<3 && col<4; row++, col++) {
       if (fourTogether(board[row][col], board[row+1][col+1], board[row+2][col+2], board[row+3][col+3])) {
          return board[row][col];
       }
     }
    //  check DIAGONAL to LEFT
   for (row=3, col=0; row<6 && col<4; row++, col++) {
       if (fourTogether(board[row][col], board[row-1][col+1], board[row-2][col+2], board[row-3][col+3])) {
         return board[row][col];
       }
     }
   return board.indexOf('-') > -1 ? 'in progress' : 'draw';
}
```

So i'm basically using the `fourTogether` function to establish 4-of-a-kind matching and also omitting the `'-'` elements (which represent unfilled boardslots).  Then in the `connectFour` function, I use four different `FOR` loops to iterate through the entire array depending on the direction checked, then I add an `IF` statement that checks the `fourTogether` function against incremented board elements.  Finally, there's a ternary statement at the end that should return either "draw" or "game in progress" if there is no 4-kind matching in the board, depending on the existence of empty `'-'` boardslots.  Unfortunately, I am returning `undefined` and i'm a bit at a loss as to where the code is failing specifically.  Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token return(…)`, move your `return` in front of the ternary operator at the end of the function. Also, `fourTogether` has no return statement

Comment: I'm pretty sure those for loops aren't doing what you expect.

Comment: thanks Paul.  I had the return statement in my fourTogether, I mistakenly omitted here.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loops, like:

```
for (row=col=0; row<3 && col<7; row++, col++) {
```

will iterate over `(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)`. What you want is `(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),...,(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),...`. To achieve this you must use nested loops:

```
for (row = 0; row<3; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col<7; col++) {
        // do that check
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I overdid it by trying to include both row and col specific loops in one `for` statement.  Thanks also for showing what exactly would be iterated over in both instances.

Answer (score 1):

Use two nested loops and check each of the four directions if you have to.

```js
var board = [['-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
             ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
             ['-','-','-','R','R','R','R'],
             ['-','-','-','Y','Y','R','Y'],
             ['-','-','-','Y','R','Y','Y'],
             ['-','-','Y','Y','R','R','R']];

function fourTogether(a,b,c,d) {
   return (a != '-') && (a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d);
}

function connectFour(board) {
  var bl = board.length, bw = board[0].length;

  // loop through the whole board once not a bunch of times
  for (var row = 0; row < bl; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < bw; col++) {
      var sq = board[row][col];
      
      // check right if we have to
      if (col < bw - 3 &&
          fourTogether(sq, board[row][col+1], board[row][col+2], board[row][col+3])) {
        return sq;
      }
      // check down if we have to
      if (row < bl - 3 &&
          fourTogether(sq, board[row+1][col], board[row+2][col], board[row+3][col])) {
        return sq;
      }
      // down right
      if (row < bl - 3 && col < bw - 3 &&
          fourTogether(sq, board[row+1][col+1], board[row+2][col+2], board[row+3][col+3])) {
        return sq;
      }
      // down left
      if (row < bl - 3 && col > 2 && 
          fourTogether(sq, board[row+1][col-1], board[row+2][col-2], board[row+3][col-3])) {
        return sq;
      }
    }      
  } 
  //board.indexOf('-') > -1 ? return 'in progress' : return 'draw'; //?????
  return "no winner";
}
alert(connectFour(board));
```

Comment: really nice solution, and got rid of a ton of unnecessary looping

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this a bit differently to you..

First, set up functions to easily get the lines to test

```
function row(board, i) {
    return board[i].join('');
}
function col(board, j) {
    return board.map(e => e[j]).join('');
}
function diagDown(board, i) {
    return board.map((e, j) => e[i - board.length + j] || '').join('');
}
function diagUp(board, i) {
    return board.slice(0).reverse().map((e, j) => e[i - board.length + j] || '').join('');
}
```

*(If you want to see what is going on with the diagonal ones try playing with a few values in the console and you'll see how it's doing the mapping)*

Now iterate over valid lines

```
function whoWon(board) {
    var i, s, r = 'RRRR', y = 'YYYY';
    // rows
    for (i = 0; i < board.length; ++i) {
        s = row(board, i);
        if (s.indexOf(r)) return 'R';
        if (s.indexOf(y)) return 'Y';
    }
    // cols
    for (i = 0; i < board[0].length; ++i) {
        s = col(board, i);
        if (s.indexOf(r)) return 'R';
        if (s.indexOf(y)) return 'Y';
    }
    // diagonals
    for (i = 4; i <= board.length + board[0].length - 4; ++i) {
        s = diagDown(board, i);
        if (s.indexOf(r)) return 'R';
        if (s.indexOf(y)) return 'Y';
        s = diagUp(board, i);
        if (s.indexOf(r)) return 'R';
        if (s.indexOf(y)) return 'Y';
    }
    return '-';
}
```

Now have

```
whoWon(board); // "R"
```

---

Also note

```
function isDraw(board) {
    return board[0].every(e => e !== '-');
}
```