# Check diagonally winner in Connect N using C

Tags: c

I'm doing the game Connect N using C and I'm having a hard time trying to code an algorithm to check if there is a winner diagonally.

```
char **BASE;
int piecesToWin, ROWS, COLS;
printf("Enter how many connected pieces to win?: ");
scanf("%d", &piecesToWin);

ROWS = 2 + piecesToWin;
COLS = 3 + piecesToWin;
BASE = (char **) malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char *)); // Allocate the row pointers
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) //  Allocate each row separately
    BASE[i] = (char *) malloc(COLS * sizeof(char));

// Fill all with space to start
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        BASE[i][j] = ' ';
```

After this, I insert a piece to the board and then, I check if there is a winner diagonally.

```
if (diagAscWin(ROWS, COLS, BASE, piecesToWin, 'X')) {
     printf("X has won!.");
}

if (diagDescWin(ROWS, COLS, BASE, piecesToWin, 'X')) {
     printf("X has won!.");
}
```

What I have tried to check diagonally:

```
bool diagAscWin(int ROWS, int COLS, char **BASE, int numToWin, char letter) {
    bool isWinner = false;
    for (int i=3; i<ROWS; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<COLS-3; j++){
            if (BASE[i][j] == letter && BASE[i-1][j+1] == letter && BASE[i-2][j+2] == letter && BASE[i-3][j+3] == letter)
                isWinner = true;
        }
    }

    return isWinner;
}

bool diagDescWin(int ROWS, int COLS, char **BASE, int numToWin, char letter) {
    bool isWinner = false;
    for (int i=3; i<ROWS; i++){
        for (int j=3; j<COLS; j++){
            if (BASE[i][j] == letter && BASE[i-1][j-1] == letter && BASE[i-2][j-2] == letter && BASE[i-3][j-3] == letter)
                isWinner = true;
        }
    }

    return isWinner;
}
```

These functions are not working. When I have N pieces diagonally, `diagAscWin` and `diagDescWin` don't see them and always return `false`. Also, I'm not sure if I need to initialize `i` or `j` with `3` or `j<COLS-3`. I was trying to replicate a solution from another thread.

Also, I have tried this:

```
bool diagRightWin(int ROWS, int COLS, char **BASE, int numToWin, char letter) {
    bool isWinner = false;
    int count;
    for (int rowStart = 0; rowStart < ROWS - 4; rowStart++) {
        count = 0;
        int row, col;
        for (row = rowStart, col = 0; row < ROWS && col < COLS; row++, col++) {
            if (BASE[row][col] == letter) {
                count++;
                if (count >= numToWin) isWinner = true;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return isWinner;
}

bool diagLeftWin(int ROWS, int COLS, char **BASE, int numToWin, char letter) {
    bool isWinner = false;
    int count;
    for (int rowStart = 0; rowStart < ROWS - 4; rowStart++) {
        count = 0;
        int row, col;
        for (row = rowStart, col = 0; row < ROWS && col < COLS; row++, col++) {
            if (BASE[row][col] == letter) {
                count++;
                if (count >= numToWin) isWinner = true;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return isWinner;
}
```

These two functions also always return `false`.

I have tried different logics with no luck. The correct thing is to check how many `numToWin` pieces are diagonally to say if there is a winner.

I have tried to replicate:

1. [Connect 4 check for a win algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770321/connect-4-check-for-a-win-algorithm)
2. [Java: How to check diagonal Connect Four win in 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062111/java-how-to-check-diagonal-connect-four-win-in-2d-array)
3. [Javascript - Connect Four game validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247472/javascript-connect-four-game-validation)
4. [Checking for a line of four (Connect Four in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506672/checking-for-a-line-of-four-connect-four-in-java)

My goal is to check if there is a winner diagonally (on any direction), having in mind that the board can be big or small, we don't know the size. What we know for sure is the `piecesToWin` which is the number of pieces that needs to be together to say there is a winner.

Comment: Can you please expand on "not working". Which part specifically is not working - what is the expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for replying. I have added more explanation to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are not exiting the function when you find a match of 4 elements. Also the function looping needs to be modified as shown.

You need two functions to check left diagonal and right diagonal

```
   /  <-- left diagonal     right diagonal --> \
  /                                             \
 /                                               \
/                                                 \
```

I have modified the check functions and also added the functionality to check for variable number of elements in a diagonal.

```
// this function checks diagnonal sloping left "/"
//
bool diagLeftWin(int ROWS, int COLS, char **BASE, int numToWin, char letter) {
    for (int i=0; i<ROWS-numToWin; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<COLS-numToWin; j++){
            char curr = BASE[i][j];  
            if (curr == letter) {
              int k;
              for (k=1; k<numToWin; k++) {
                  if (curr != BASE[i+k][j+k]) {
                     break;
                  }
              }
              if (k == numToWin) {
                  // match found
                  return true;
              }
            }                   
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// this function checks diagnonal sloping right "\"
//
bool diagLeftWin(int ROWS, int COLS, char **BASE, int numToWin, char letter) {
    for (int i=ROWS-numToWin; i>=0; i--){
        for (int j=0; j<COLS-numToWin; j++){
            char curr = BASE[i][j]; 
            if (curr == letter) {
              int k;                
              for (k=1; k<numToWin; k++) {
                  if (curr != BASE[i-k][j+k]) {
                     break;
                  }
              }
              if (k == numToWin) {
                  // match found
                  return true;
              } 
            }                   
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

These functions check the entire board every time. You can optimise it to only check around newly added pieces to the board.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - You are correct. I have modified it.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje The `if (k == numToWin)` condition is outside of the last `for` in both functions. I have tried to move it inside but, both functions doesn't work, always return `false`. I have tried to place peaces together diagonally on any direction and both functions always return `false`.

Comment: @RRGT19 - The condition `if (k == numToWin)` checks whether the match is received for a particular value of `BASE[i][j]`. This represents the starting point for the pattern. If the match is received for any starting point, then the function exits with `true`

Comment: The condition should not be moved from it's current location. If you still are not getting the diagonal with the value, you should tell us an example value of the entire `BASE` array for which the function is failing. you can make an [mcve] by initailizing the array with example value.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I will do a reproducible example. In the meanwhile, what I've tried to mean is this, look at this screenshot: https://ibb.co/4YGFb9X. The `if (k == numToWin)` is not evaluated because it's outside the for. I don't know if this is intentional or we need to use `j` instead of `k`.

Comment: @RRGT19 - Please see the updated code. I have updated the scope of the `k` variable.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I have tried different angles and the functions only works sometimes but, don't work for the most basic scenario, having the same letter diagonally from bottom left towards the top right. I didn't know how to insert a snippet using C here, so I have created a working example with the non-functional case for you to see and test: https://codeshare.io/5wWJ9P. You can copy it and paste it in your IDE to run it.